# I converted a KML file into a PostGIS db using ogr2ogr. How do I publish all the tables as separate layers?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, kml, curl

As the title says, I converted/imported a KML file into my PostGIS database using the `ogr2ogr` command. Now I am trying to publish each table as a separate layer onto a GeoServer. I know about cURL, but as far as I can see, I would have to have a new command for each table in the db. I have 124 tables I need to publish, so doing that one by one would be labor-intensive. Is there anyway straight-forward way to streamline this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use this example to build up a script: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#adding-a-postgis-table

Using Python, you could list all the tables in your postgis database, then craft a HTML call (using [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)) to publish each one.

Issues you might have include styling, to name just one. And you might want to set up a metadata table to read from (could be a CSV or spreadsheet) in order to set up the specifics for each table.

When you have a table with your specifics for your 124 tables, then use the python script to set it all up on GeoServer. Perhaps you write your script to do the following (assuming you have your datastore set up):

1. delete your workspace and all layers, if they exist
2. create your workspace
3. populate the workspace with all your tables, using parameters from your metadata spreadsheet

That way, if it works, you're good. And if it doesn't, or you want an additional 20 tables, you can simply re-run the script. And, if it doesn't work, you can fix the problem and re-run the script!

Good luck =)

Edit: note that there is an excellent python library to hit the GeoServer API with: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig

Comment: Thanks for the help! What type of datastore should I put them in?

Comment: Sorry, the word is just store. It's the PostGIS connection. A store defines a dataset or group of datasets.

Comment: Also, rather than crafting URLs, use this library for Python: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig